# configure request param for action to be assigned to fields of bean

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

I am using `www.datatables.net`. JS framework to show data in tables. It has server mode and it sends a lot of params during this mode.

Example: `sortColumn`, `sortType(asc,desc)`, filter values, `pagenum`, `itemsonpage` and so on.

So i handle it in action. i assign to each request param field in action and it work fine.

But now i have several table. So i have to make different actions but request params same and there are a lots of them. It is not a good idea to copy paste code from one action to another.

So i did implement a `DatatableParamBean` which contain all params needed to work properly.

problem is that params send this way `iSortColumn`, `iDisplayTotalLength`, `iTotalItems` and so on
but i need to them to be assigned to bean fields.

```
bean.iSortColumn, bean.iDisplayTotalLength and so on.
```

Consider that `DatatableParamBean` has reference in my action class as 'bean';

If there is a way to override default mechanism of assigning request param values?
Only solution i found for now is to create an action say `DatatableAction` class with all this params and create an new action if i need to handle dataatble, using extending from `DatatableAction`

Comment: No, ognl should handle those params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usual way to associate or aggregate a bean to the action class. The action class properties can be used directly by name that have property accessors. Nested beans properties are accessible via OGNL by specifying proper OGNL expression which is a *path* to the property. Assumed all properties accessors have not `null` references to beans. That could be achieved via providing corresponding getters and setters to properties and initializing bean references if necessary.  So, `bean.iSortColumn`, `bean.iDisplayTotalLength` are valid OGNL expressions to set/get the `bean` properties. But you need to initialize it in the action. Like this

```
private Bean bean = new Bean();

public Bean getBean() { return bean; }
```

**References:**

- To be familiar how OGNL works you can read in the [OGNL Basics](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl-basics).
- The base [OGNL](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl) reference including a link to the OGNL language guide.

Comment: Actual problem was from other side. I was successfully implement using action field as params, Problem was that i was not able to change param coming from js framework, but now i did manage that. datatable has special function to override param name.

Comment: Two additional options are available to you: 1) You can implement `ModelDriven<DatatableParamBean>`; 2) Use `alias` interceptor.