# get a property of an object stored in session in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have created a UserSession dto object and added many fields in that like `lastloginTime`,`lastAccessedTime`, `userName` etc.
I want to display these in jsp using OGNL concept of Struts2
I have written

```
<li class="current_page_item"><b>Last Login Time <s:property value="#session.USROBJECT"/> </b></li>
```

In action, I have written

```
sessionMap.put("USROBJECT", us);
```

I am getting the object on jsp, but I want to display its fields.

Comment: us is an object of UserSession class

Comment: You know that you don't *need* to put them in session to read them in the page, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#session` object is always available from the value stack

```jsp
<s:property value="#session.USROBJECT.lastloginTime"/>
<s:property value="#session.USROBJECT.lastAccessedTime"/>
<s:property value="#session.USROBJECT.userName "/>
```

You should create getters for fields `lastloginTime`,`lastAccessedTime`, `userName` etc.

Details and references you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21186611/573032).

But `sessionMap` you should inject with the `SessionAware` interface implemented by the action class. It's a preferable method.

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17252350/573032) how to implement `SessionAware` interface.

Comment: Thanks,it solved my problem. I made public setters and getters for the UserSession object.